# Linq Group Object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of customer objects where I am having trouble understanding how to properly group this into a new object.

```
public class CustomerOrders
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string OrderType { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    
    public string Account { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have a new object list to access with the CustomerOrders grouped by:

- CustomerId
- OrderType
- OrderDate
- List of Account, Amount and ClientId as these repeat for the CustomerId, OrderType and OrderDate

Also is there a way to add a few null properties where I can populate later through an iteration to this new list for example "Approved" to the Grouped fields?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to accomplish this. It would be better if this class was an entity and the account, amount, and clientid were fields in another table that can be joined to the customer data.

Below is my example from linqpad.

```
void Main()
{
    List<CustomerOrders> orders = new List<CustomerOrders>() {
        new CustomerOrders() {CustomerId = "1", OrderType = "1", OrderDate = DateTime.Now, Account = "1234", Amount = 2.2M, ClientId = "asdf"},
        new CustomerOrders() {CustomerId = "1", OrderType = "1", OrderDate = DateTime.Now, Account = "1235", Amount = 5.3M, ClientId = "hjkl"},
        new CustomerOrders() {CustomerId = "2", OrderType = "3", OrderDate = DateTime.Now, Account = "1236", Amount = 6.2M, ClientId = "zxcv"}
    };
    
    var data = 
        from o in orders
        group new { o.CustomerId, o.OrderType, o.OrderDate } by new { o.CustomerId, o.OrderType, o.OrderDate } into grouped
        select new Results {
            CustomerId = grouped.First().CustomerId,
            OrderType = grouped.First().OrderType,
            OrderDate = grouped.First().OrderDate,
            Data = 
                orders.Where(x => 
                    x.CustomerId == grouped.First().CustomerId &&
                    x.OrderType == grouped.First().OrderType &&
                    x.OrderDate == grouped.First().OrderDate
                ).Select(d => new CustomerOrderData {
                    Account = d.Account,
                    Amount = d.Amount,
                    ClientId = d.ClientId
                })
        };
        
    data.Dump();
}

    public class CustomerOrders
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    
        public string OrderType { get; set; }
    
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        
        public string Account { get; set; }
    
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class CustomerOrderData {
        public string Account { get; set; }
    
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Results
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    
        public string OrderType { get; set; }
    
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        
        public bool? Approved { get; set; } // adding null property
        
        public IEnumerable<CustomerOrderData> Data { get; set; }
    }
```